# Parse a web page with HAP LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a wp 8.1 application that takes a web page content. My problem is that xpath doesn't seem to work for WP8.1, so i'm trying to use LinQ, but i don't understand it very well.
The page is this:

```
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-style:none; padding:0; margin:0;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_groupPlaceholderContainer">               
         <tbody>
             <tr style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; background-image:none; vertical-align:top;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer">         
                 <td style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; width:22%;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_ctl01_Td3">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <a target="_self" title="PH1" href="fumetto.aspx?Fumetto=279277">PH1_1</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; background-image:none; vertical-align:top;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer">          
                 <td style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; width:22%;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_ctl01_Td3">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <a target="_self" title="PH2" href="fumetto.aspx?Fumetto=279277">PH2_1</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; background-image:none; vertical-align:top;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer">          
                 <td style="border-style:none;padding:0; margin:0; width:22%;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListView1_ctrl0_ctl01_Td3">
                    <div class="photo">
                        <a target="_self" title="PH3" href="fumetto.aspx?Fumetto=279277">PH3_1</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

I want to save the attributes "PH1", "PH2", "PH3" and the values "PH1_1", "PH2_1", "PH3_1". Can you help me? My code is this:

```
string filePath = "...";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(filePath);
if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
    // Handle any parse errors as required
}
else
{
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        //I'm trying to get the first node for now
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode aNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf("a").FirstOrDefault();
        if (aNode != null)
        {
            string first = aNode.GetAttributeValue("title", "null");
            string value = aNode.ToString();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: The problem is that `first` is `"null"` and `value` is `"htmlAgilitypack"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `DescendantsAndSelf()` with `Descendants()` :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode aNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                                        .Descendants("a")
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

And instead of calling `ToString()`, use `InnerText` property to get the text between opening and cloaing tag :

```
if (aNode != null)
{
    string first = aNode.GetAttributeValue("title", "null");
    string value = aNode.InnerText;
    .....
}
```

**[[.NET fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/61fc10)]**

Comment: `aNode` is `null` now.. If i keep `DescendantsAndSelf()`, i get `"null"` for `first` and the link of the page for `value`.

Comment: Not sure about `DescendantsAndSelf()`, it kinda returns the wrong element for me (maybe a bug in HAP, didn't check further). But `Descendants()` should work, see the demo [in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/61fc10)

Comment: Another question. How can i get the html node if i have something like this? i always get the first node and never the second one.
`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>...</body></html>`

Comment: having `<!DOCTYPE html>` node added, the `<html>` node is also preserved for me see [another demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6iD3I)

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to reproduce your problem. Do you see the expected HTML markup in `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`?

Comment: Because `LoadHtml()` expect *HTML string* as parameter. Print `OuterHtml` as I suggested and it will be clear to you why (the document contains url string instead of HTML!!). Use `HtmlWeb` to generate `HtmlDocument` from Url : `var htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("the url here");`